# How to create a document on memory nodejs, because I have variable with csv data, but i don't know how to send the file with out save it

Tags: node.js

How to create a docuement on memory nodejs, because I have variable with csv data, but i don't know how to send the file without saving it.

```
fs.readFile('./test-data.json', 'utf-8', (err, fileContent) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err); // Do something to handle the error or just throw it
    throw new Error(err);
  }
  const csvData = csvjson.toCSV(fileContent, {
    headers: 'key'
  });
  fs.writeFile('./test-data.csv', csvData, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err); // Do something to handle the error or just throw it
      throw new Error(err);
    }
    console.log('Success!');
    bot.sendDocument(chatId, './test-data.csv');
  });
});
```

Comment: Convert your CSV file to byte format instead of writing to some file. Then you can send it

Comment: I'm a little confused about what you want to do. Your fs.ReadFile returns a buffer of the file (the file is in memory) and your csvData is the csvData in memory. If you do not want to save it, can you not skip fs.writeFile use the data you're already holding in memory?

Comment: well, the problem is that i want to send csvData but I don't want to use the server to save any document, but I have to send the document with a method that ask me a document or link.